# Python Selenium find all CSS element and replace all

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I want to change the CSS element style using Python Selenium while doing automation to change the theme color of the page. For example, the page element is as follows:

```
<div style="background: #e7e7e7">
   <div style="border-bottom: #e7e7e7; border-top: #e7e7e7">
```

I want to change the color from `#e7e7e7` to `#318c89`, which means I need to find all `e7e7e7` in the HTML script and replace all with `#318c89` but I have no idea how should I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
script = "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll('#e7e7e7', '#318c89')"
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses JavaScript to replace all text in dom with given text executed by selenium execute JavaScript function.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

# Run with Chrome window visible
DRIVER_PATH = 'path to driver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("webpage url")
# change to first colour
js = """
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll('#e7e7e7 ', '#318c89')
console.log("Hello World");
"""
driver.execute_script(js)
sleep(10)
# change back
js = """
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll('#318c89 ', '#e7e7e7')
console.log("Hello World");
"""
driver.execute_script(js)
sleep(60)

driver.quit()
```